# Passing CSV to Excel Workbook (Not From File)

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, csv

I have a folder of CSV files that contain log entries. For each entry of the CSV, if the Risk property is not Low and not None then I put it in an accumulation CSV object. From there, **I want to import it into an Excel Workbook directly WITHOUT having to save the CSV to file**.

```
$CSVPaths = (Split-Path $PSCommandPath)
$AccumulateExportPath = (Split-Path $PSCommandPath)
$FileName="Accumulate"
$Acc=@()

Foreach ($csv in (Get-ChildItem C:\Scripts\Nessus\Sheets |? {$_.Extension -like ".csv" -and $_.BaseName -notlike "$FileName"}))
{
    $Content = Import-CSV $csv.FullName
    Foreach ($Log in $Content)
    {
        If ($Log.Risk -ne "None" -and $Log.Risk -ne "Low")
        {
            $Acc+=$Log
        }
    }
}

$CSV = $ACC |ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation

Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
$Script:Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible=$True
#$Excel.Workbooks.OpenText($CSV) What should replace this?
```

Is there a Method like [OpenText()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/workbooks-opentext-method-excel) that lets me pass a CSV **object** instead of a **filepath** to a CSV file or am I going to have to write my own conversion function?

Comment: Why don't you want to save the csv as temporary file? Seems to me the easiest way.

Comment: @FunThomas Because if there's a function that allows me to pass a CSV object, why should I create a temporary file? If there's not a function that can do that, then I will use a temporary file.

Comment: The scripting guy wrote an Plugin for that, but I don't know if that will be easier to use at the end of the day. See https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/11/25/introducing-the-powershell-excel-module-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. I'm not aware of a method that allows you to pass a CSV **Object**.

However, if your result CSV is not too big and you are using PowerShell 5.0+ you could convert the object to a **string** and leverage [Set-Clipboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.management/set-clipboard) ([more info](http://www.workingsysadmin.com/new-stuff-get-clipboard-and-set-clipboard-new-in-powershell-5-0/))

```
$headers =  ($csv | Get-Member | Where-Object {$_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty"}).Name
$delim   = "`t"

# headers
foreach($header in $headers){
    $myString += $header + $delim
}

# trim delimiter at the end, and add new line
$myString = $myString.TrimEnd($delim)
$myString = $myString + "`n"

# loop over each line and repeat
foreach($line in $csv){
    foreach($header in $headers){
        $myString += $line.$header + $delim
    }
    $myString = $myString.TrimEnd($delim)
    $myString = $myString + "`n"
}

# copy to clipboard
Set-Clipboard $myString

# paste into excel from clipboard
$Excel.Workbooks.Worksheets.Item(1).Paste()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to create an Excel spreadsheet from PowerShell without writing a .csv file.

```
$dirs = 'C:\src\t', 'C:\src\sql'

$records = $()
$records = foreach ($dir in $dirs) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -File '*.txt' -Recurse |
        Select-Object @{Expression={$_.FullName}; Label="filename"}
    }

#open excel
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$excel.visible = $false

#add a default workbook

$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
#remove worksheet 2 & 3

$workbook.Worksheets.Item(3).Delete()
$workbook.Worksheets.Item(2).Delete()

#give the remaining worksheet a name
$uregwksht = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$uregwksht.Name = 'File Names'

# Start on row 1
$i = 1

# the .appendix to $record refers to the column header in the csv file
foreach ($record in $records) {
    $excel.cells.item($i,1) = $record.filename
    $i++
}

#adjusting the column width so all data's properly visible
$usedRange = $uregwksht.UsedRange
$usedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit() | Out-Null

#saving & closing the file
$outputpath = Join-Path -Path $Env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath "desktop\exceltest.xlsx"
$workbook.SaveAs($outputpath)
$excel.Quit()
```